# getElementById in jQuery

Tags: jquery, prompt, getelementbyid

How can I safely convert this to jQuery, specially the prompt part without any problems with IE.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function fixnumber()
{
var str=prompt("Please enter number");
if (str!=null && str!="")
  {

  var fixed=str.substr(1,10);

  document.getElementById('txt1').value=fixed;

  }
}
</script>
```

Number TEST: `<input name="textbox1" type="text" id="txt1"/>`

```
<input name="buttonExecute" onclick="fixnumber(document.getElementById('txt1'))" type="button" value="Enter number" />`
```

Comment: Why `substr(1,10)`? You don't want the left-most digit?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are trying to do. Why do you have a button that calls fixnumber with an argument when fixnumber() does not take and argument and creates a prompt?

Comment: the prompt will open a box where I will scan a barcode with a barcode scanner, the substr(1,10) is to cut the barcode to a number that is needed.

Answer (score 3):

Change:

```
document.getElementById('txt1').value=fixed;
```

To:

```
$('#txt1').val(fixed);
```

Comment: How about prompt part done in jQuery, IE does not like this code.

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="txt1" name="textbox1">
<input type="button" id="btn" name="buttonExecute" value="Enter number">
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#btn').click(function() {
    var n = prompt('Please enter number');
    if ( n ) {
        $('#txt1').val(n);
    }
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/3vxKW/1/

Comment: Sime, how can this be done safely in IE, try this in IE and you get the security warning for the prompt part.

Comment: @Ntguy It works in IE9. Unfortunately I don't have older versions of IE on my machine.

Comment: @Ntguy You could use jQuery UI instead of the prompt: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/